# An internalized version of Tennenbaum's Theorem

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, peano-arithmetic

Tennenbaum's celebrated  1959 theorem (see [here](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/papers/tennenbaum/tennenbaum.pdf) for a reference) is certainly one of the key theorems in mathematical logic. Not so much for its proof, but because it helps "isolating" $N$ as something very special: *it is the only countable model of Peano arithmetic which is recursive*.

But, does it?

Suppose I live inside any countable model $M$ of Peano:  I think I am actually living in the standard natural numbers, and addition/multiplication are the standard ones (and so are all the recursive function, etc). So, it would seem that from the point of view of $M$, other PA-models are not recursive. To be a bit more precise, let me state this:

**Internalized Tennenbaum Theorem (ITT): Let $M$ be a countable model of Peano. Then, for any other countable model $N$ not isomorphic to $M$, $N$ is not recursive in  $M$, ie it is not $\Delta_1$-definable in M.**

> Question: Can ITT be proved in, say, ZFC? If not, what is the
> obstruction?

Post Scriptum.

Thanks to Emil Jerabek for his suggestion: rather than the original misleading name, Derived Tennenbaum, use Internal (or Internalized).
The original name generated some confusion, see the comments of Francois Dorais,
thus I decided to rename the question. The recursivity required is IN the model, not FROM the model.

Comment: The main obstruction would be that the statement is false. Maybe you meant to relativize "Peano" as well? If so, please explain how. (See the well-studied notion of [PA-degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA_degree).)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais pardon me, perhaps my question is entirely dumb, but can you please elaborate on the falsehood of this statement? Obviously, recursivity in M is not computable in the real world, but from the point of view of M I can still express the notion of being recursive, or not? So where does  exactly break down?

Comment: To be a bit more precise: M and N are both countable. Take ANY injective set map f : N into M . RTT would be the statement that the images of N-addition and N-multiplication via f are not M-recursive

Comment: The RTT statement is false because if $M$ is nonstandard then the standard model is not isomorphic to $M$ but the standard model is recursive.

Comment: I’m pretty sure Tennenbaum’s theorem is provable in PA, which, translated to model-theoretic terms, means that no proper extension $M'$ satisfying PA of a model $M$ of PA is $\Sigma_1$-definable in $M$. (Note that such internally definable models are automatically end-extensions.) This should also hold for much weaker theories than PA. Perhaps there might be a version that applies to proper end-extensions that are merely externally relatively computable rather than $\Sigma_1$-definable, but I don’t think that any such thing stands a chance to hold when $M'$ is not an extension of $M$.

Comment: (In principle, I should have written “proper extension $M'$ of $M$ such that $M$ thinks $M'$ is a model of PA” rather than “proper extension $M'$ satisfying PA”, but since, as I mentioned, this should hold even for much weaker, finitely axiomatizable fragments of PA, the distinction does not matter.)

Comment: Rereading the question, it's starting to dawn on me that when you write "$M$-recursive", you perhaps *do* in fact mean " $\Sigma_1$-definable in $M$" rather than "computable with oracle $M$" (which is how François and me interpreted it). If so, you really, really shouldn't call it "relative" or "relativized" Tennenbaum theorem, but something like "internal" or "internalized" TT. "Relativized" unambiguously refers to computability with an oracle.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais the standard model is recursive, but it is not M-recursive (ie  Σ1-definable in M). I would suggest you read what Emil just commented.

Comment: @Emil: as usual, your comments are pointed and informative. And, as usual, I invite you to expand them  (at your leisure, of course) into a complete answer. PS YES, I did not mean computable with oracle M, rather sigma_1 definable in M. Accepted the change from "relative" to "internalized": the Internalized Tennebaum Theorem, or, how every M believes it is the only recursive model of PA. I wish Stan were still alive, I am sure he would have laughed loud....

Comment: @EmilJeřábek re-christened the question

Comment: Ok, I will try to write it up as an answer, but it may take a while, as I’m out of office at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

To move this off the unanswered queue, let me summarize the situation as correctly explained by the comments above:

The standard proof of Tennenbaum's theorem goes through inside $\mathsf{PA}$: $\mathsf{PA}$ proves that there is no $\Delta_1$ description of a model of $I\Sigma_1$. (As usual, $\mathsf{PA}$ can be replaced with something vastly weaker here; at a glance, already $I\Sigma_1$ should be enough.)

One key point here is that $\mathsf{PA}$ *can* quantify over $\Delta_1$ descriptions since this only involves reference to a bounded truth predicate. (Something like "There is no *definable* structure such that [stuff]" would have to be expressed as a *scheme*, but that's not an issue here.)

On the other hand, $\mathsf{PA}$ **cannot** express "the structure defined by the formula tuple $\Phi$ satisfies $\mathsf{PA}$" *(at least not as cleanly as one might hope - we'd need to talk about explicitly-Skolemized structures, and that's a whole annoying rabbit hole to go down)*. This is why I've used $I\Sigma_1$ as the "Tennenbaum target:" as a finitely axiomatizable theory, $\mathsf{PA}$ has no trouble talking about its satisfaction (or not) in a defined structure, again by virtue of the satisfactoriness of a bounded truth predicate.

Comment: let me process what you wrote (meanwhile you got already my vote, at the very least for trying to sum up the above). .  The last comment of Emil was "Ok, I will try to write it up as an answer, but it may take a while,".